# Manipulating quadratic form

Tags: covariance, matrix

I cannot make the transition from the first to the second line:
$X,V$ are matrices with $V$ being a covariance matrix, $y, \beta$ vectors:

$$(y-X\hat\beta+X\hat\beta-X\beta)^TV^{-1}(y-X\hat\beta+X\hat\beta-X\beta)=
$$
$$
(y-X\hat\beta)^TV^{-1}(y-X\hat\beta)+(\beta-\hat \beta)^T(X^TV^{-1}X)(\beta-\hat\beta)+2(\hat\beta-\beta)^TX^TV^{-1}(y-X\hat\beta)
$$

I think there is some kind of binomial formula involved but I have no clue how it works for matrices.

UPDATE:

I found it. In general

$$
(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) = x^T \Sigma^{-1} x - 2x^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu + \mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu
$$

Comment: It is Newton's binomial formula for $n=2$: $(a+b)^2 =a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ :) Actually it is just simple matrix multiplication, which term do you have a problem with?

Comment: @mpiktas what is the a and b here and where is the square? I still do not see the binomial here.

Comment: You should emphasize that your "general" statement requires $\Sigma^{-1}$ to be symmetric (which of course is true of covariance matrices).

Answer (score 3):

Start by applying the transpose on the left paranthesis

$$(y-X\hat\beta+X\hat\beta-X\beta)^T=
$$

$$(y^T-\hat\beta^T X^T+\hat\beta^T X^T-\beta^T X^T)
$$
Now just treat all the individual terms as numbers and multiply out the parentheses, just like you multiply 
$$
(a+b)\cdot V\cdot(c+d)=...
$$

Just be careful that $V^{-1}$ multiplies to the right of the left parenthesis and vice versa for the right one, i.e. the multiplication is not commutative.
Then gather the terms and take the transpose operator outside some parentheses.